# Laravel Spark license and Heroku Pipeline

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-spark, heroku-pipelines

So, I have a Laravel Spark license and I recently upgraded my code from Spark version 3 to 6. I decided that before i push that big of a change, I should go ahead and set up a pipeline with a staging app (like I should have done months ago).

I am trying to push the current working version of my code to the staging app just to make sure the staging app works before I merge the branch with the changes to V6 and push it. The heroku build for the staging app fails with the standard error that I can't get the spark repo.

Is this because I upgraded to V6 and the code is trying to get v3 (doubtful) or is my Laravel Spark license not recognized for the staging app (more likely)? Any ideas on how to address this?

Error message below ...

```
Failed to download laravel/spark from dist: The 
"https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark/zipball/#" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)Now trying to download from source. Installing laravel/spark (v3.0.5): Cloning ....
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Would https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/08/24/spark-heroku.html help in any way?

Comment: I added the error message. Pretty sure it just means that i have permission issues or something like that. This is Laravel-Spark and not the other Spark.

Comment: Is this related to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/spark-install-fails-to-production-server/replies/193581?

Comment: "standard error message"... I see you have seen that before: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42836505/6309 (the question has since been deleted)

Comment: Yes. It's a tough problem to crack. I originally had to purchase a new license just because I was so tired of messing with it. I have joined the github repo and can see that from my github. I think that the problem is that the license limits me to one repo and counts the second staging repo as requiring a separate license.